# Helm Chart from different Repository

Tags: azure-devops, kubernetes-helm

I do have multiple repositories like Project1, Project2, Project3.
I do have 1 repository where Helm charts are managed (deploy1).
I do this on Azure DevOps.

I now added a build Pipepline to Project1, which is working as expected.
Now i went into project deploy1 and wanted to create a new Release Pipeline, which is to be triggerd from Project1 build.
Now i would want to use the Helm chart from deploy1 to deploy to my kubernetes Cluster based on the published build from Project1.

Is this possible, is this even the correct approach?

Some might suggest that i keep the Helm Chart within Project1, but isnt that counter intuitive?
I also do not want to keep a copy of the same Helm Chart in every Projectn repository.
As i understood a Helm chart is used to manage a set of kubernetes Resources.
And if possible i would like to be able to remove my entire applicationstack, Project1, Project2 & Project3 with the unstill command from 1 Helm file.

Answer (score 1):

well, I'd suggest using Azure Container Registry (acr) to store helm charts. That way you can use repo1 as source for all helm charts, when you'd build the charts, you'd package them and push to the acr. Then in other releases you'd use the same acr to pull those charts and apply them.

this can be done with az cli:

```
helm package --version $(build.buildId) --destination $(build.artifactStagingDirectory) %name%
az acr helm push %name%.tgz
```

you can pull them with az as well